GRUB_TIMEOUT=3 # Ignored?
Newly installed Ubuntu 24.04, I'm in the process of adapting it to my liking...
One thing is to delay minimally at the grub menu, though always show it.
Hope the info below can tell what might be wrong,
as this should set it to delay at grub menu in 3 seconds, but this is apparently ignored.
The actual delay is showing a countdown from 30 seconds - which I believe is some sort of default.
$ . /etc/os-release ; echo $PRETTY_NAME
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS

$ grep '^GRUB_' /etc/default/grub
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=3
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`( . /etc/os-release; echo ${NAME:-Ubuntu} ) 2>/dev/null || echo Ubuntu`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

$ sudo update-grub2  # or just "sudo update-grub"
[sudo] password for hannu: 
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: vmlinuz-6.8.0-31-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_xxxxxx
Found initrd image: initrd.img-6.8.0-31-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_xxxxxx
Found memtest86+ 64bit EFI image: /BOOT/ubuntu_xxxxxx@/memtest86+x64.efi
Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done

$ reboot


Does this help? https://superuser.com/a/971719/1834793

I got this to work with the help of what @mpboden pointed out;
(https://superuser.com/a/971719/1834793) - to tell:
$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub
# edit the line at GRUB_TIMEOUT to be as shown, and add the following line
GRUB_TIMEOUT=3
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=$GRUB_TIMEOUT

This one was "hidden" before (above), might be required to be "menu"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu

save, and then, note that:
$ sudo ls -l `which update-grub2`
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 apr  4 12:12 /usr/sbin/update-grub2 -> update-grub

so either of:
$ sudo update-grub2
$ sudo update-grub

... has the same effect, activating the change.
(By rebuilding grub.cfg in /boot/grub )
... all this has the effect that the menu actually is shown for three seconds,
and the splash screen won't appear.
(The latter I consider be good, as the splash-screen will continue to 'rotate' forever - even if there is a mishap in the startup that pauses or stops it)

Glad you got it figured out. I had to implement this same fix on one of my servers as well.
